# Django forms workaround

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm a bit confused with all the django stuff and forms, I hope you can help me.

I'm migrating a cmd line app to django, and I think I don't need to mess with models (db) atm.  I just would like to pass the parameters filled in a form to a python script that use these fields as parameters. I would like to keep my html code and skip render the form with a python form class since it has a lot of css code inside each one.

At the moment I have this form:

```
<form class="nobottommargin" id="template-contactform" name="template-contactform" action="{% url 'get_data' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

    <div class="col_half">
        <label for="name">Project Name <small>*</small></label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="{{ current_name }}"  class="sm-form-control required" />
    </div>

    <div class="col_half col_last">
        <label for="group">Project Group <small>*</small></label>
        <input type="text" id="group" name="group" value="{{ current_group }}" class="required sm-form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="col_half">
        <label for="version">Project Version<small>*</small></label>
        <input type="text" id="version" name="version" value="{{ current_version }}" class="required sm-form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="col_half col_last">
        <label for="pType">Project Type<small>*</small></label>
        <select id="pType" name="pType" class="required sm-form-control">
            <option value="">-- Select One --</option>
            <option value="bundle">Bundle</option>
            <option value="multiple">Multiple</option>
            <option value="git">Git</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col_half">
        <label for="pPath">Project path<small>*</small></label>
        <input type="text" id="pPath" name="pPath" value="{{ current_path }}" class="required sm-form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="col_full hidden">
        <input type="text" id="template-contactform-botcheck" name="template-contactform-botcheck" value="" class="sm-form-control" />
    </div>


    <div class="col_full" style="margin: 50px 0 0 0 ">
        <button class="button button-3d nomargin" type="submit" id="template-contactform-submit" name="template-contactform-submit" value="submit">Create Project</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

So, I want to figure out what's the best way to write the **get_data** function. I also need some sort of custom validation about some fields that involves other checks that exceeds the basic checks, such as max_chars on each field. That means I need to create some sort of my own **form.is_valid()** function.

Hope you can help me!
Regards

Comment: Kiki, welcome to SO! :) Please, take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to earn your first shiny badge ;)

Comment: You should include your view. Django's Form class will allow you to use a form without a model in which you can add your validation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/